# Ошибка при выполнении json.load()

Tags: python, json

При выполнении данного куска кода, появляется ошибка, хотя все написано вроде бы правильно. Прошу помощи.

Код:

```
import json

with open('database.json', 'r') as file:
    data = json.load(file)
print(data)
```

Файл database.json:

```
data = {
    "president": {
        "name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox",
        "species": "Betelgeusian"
    }
}
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Projects\Programming\Python\Teaching\teaching.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = json.load(file)
  File "C:\Users\Jokimazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Jokimazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Jokimazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Jokimazi\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В файле не должно быть переменной, только сами данные.

Чтобы получить нормальный json, запишите его!

```python
with open('database.json', 'w') as file:
    file.write(json.dumps(data))
```

###### Содержание файла:

```
{"president": {"name": "Zaphod Beeblebrox", "species": "Betelgeusian"}}
```

Теперь такой файл открывается без проблем.

Подробнее о структуре json файлов можно почитать [здесь](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-404/).